# How to sort multidimensional PHP array (recent news time based implementation)

Tags: php, json, xml, rss

i got some recent news rss in xml format and change in to json format , it is needed for android application to display recent news. i have an following JSON array ...

```
{
    "rss_news": [
        {
            "title": " ",
            "rss_original_src": "recent_news1(google news)",
            "rss_original_src_img": "",
            "link": "",
            "pubDate": "Tue, 19 Apr 2016 14:05:47 +0530",
            "description": ""
        },
 {
            "title": " ",
            "rss_original_src": "recent_news2(yahoo news)",
            "rss_original_src_img": "",
            "link": "",
            "pubDate": "Tue, 19 Apr 2016 16:05:47 +0530",
            "description": ""
        },
 {
            "title": " ",
            "rss_original_src": "recent_news3",
            "rss_original_src_img": "",
            "link": "",
            "pubDate": "Tue, 19 Apr 2016 11:05:47 +0530",
            "description": ""
        },
....
]
}
```

---

Now i need ... PHP multi dimensional array sort based on value(pubDate)..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: ok..what have you tried this far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your JSON string to PHP array using `json_decode`.

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array like.

```
usort($array, 'sortByDate');

function sortByDate($a, $b) {
    $date1=$a['pubDate'];
    $date2=$b['pubDate'];

   //return value based on above two dates.
}
```

Comment: usort($final, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['pubDate'] - $b['pubDate'];
});   // This is working.. thanks...