# Reorder array items depending on substring representing time in php

Tags: php, arrays, time

Hi buddies :) I'm required to reorder an array which contains several items with a given format. For example, like this:

*m=11:00_12:00,d=10:00_10:30,a=13:00_13:30*

As we can see, any item's given format is a string like *x=whateverinitialhour_whateverfinalhour*

As stated before, I have to reorder these items depending on initial hour, so the expected result should be:

*d=10:00_10:30,m=11:00_12:00,a=13:00_13:30*

Well, I have been searching a lot and found *usort*, and I found similar questions too like [How to sort multidimensional PHP array (recent news time based implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717455/how-to-sort-multidimensional-php-array-recent-news-time-based-implementation)

So, I'm coding this:

```
$arr = array();
$newarr = array();
$arr = ('m=11:00_12:00','d=10:00_10:30','a=13:00_13:30');
usort($arr, function($a,$b) {return strtotime(substr($a[0],2,5))-strtotime(substr($b[0],2,5));});
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $newarr[] = $value;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting the expected result, and the new array contains this:

*m=11:00_12:00,a=13:00_13:30,d=10:00_10:30*

Which it is not reordered by every item's initial hour :(

What am I doing wrong? Am I not using usort in a rigth way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `usort()` function,

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b) {
    return strtotime(substr($a[0],2,5))-strtotime(substr($b[0],2,5));
                            ^^^^^                        ^^^^^
});
```

`$a` and `$b` are not arrays, they are elements of the array. Also, you don't need a new array to store the sorted array, `usort()` applies the manipulation in the original array itself. So your code should be like this:

```
$arr = array('m=11:00_12:00','d=10:00_10:30','a=13:00_13:30');
usort($arr, function($a,$b){ 
    return (strtotime(substr($a,2,5)) < strtotime(substr($b,2,5))) ? -1 : 1; 
});

var_dump($arr);
```